# Decreasing value in Bootstrap notification badge only works once after Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap badge that displays the number of messages.

[image: badge]

When the user clicks the icon, a modal appears that displays messages from the database. They have the option to delete the message (it doesn't actually delete, it just sets an integer to 1 so it doesn't display). After deleting once, the message div is removed, the database sets the field to '1', and the notification badge decreases by 1.

[image: not deleted yet]

After deleting 1 message:

[image: deleted]

After deleting second message without page refresh:

[image: problem!!!]

This is a problem. However, once I refresh, it hides the badge as it's supposed to upon being less than 1.

[image: correct]

The badge text is generated from a PHP script that queries the database for the messages. For each row that it finds, I increment the notification:

```
$query = "SELECT username, avatar, conversation_id, conversation_subject, time, msg_seen FROM `users` INNER JOIN `conversation` ON `users`.id = `conversation`.user_1
                          WHERE user_2 = ? AND user_2_deleted = ? ORDER BY time DESC";
            if (!$stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
                echo $stmt->error;
            } else {
                if (!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $recip_id, $user_2_deleted)) {
                    echo $stmt->error;
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($sender_name, $avatar, $msg_id, $subject, $timestamp, $msg_seen);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {                         
                        if ($msg_seen == 0) {
                            $notification_count++; // RIGHT HERE
                        }
```

Here is the corresponding jquery/ajax that removes the message div, sends the ajax call, and alerts that the message was deleted. Everything except for the badge text value works more than once per page refresh. I have to refresh the page to see 0 notifications. Why?

```
//Find notification badge and display count
$(document).ready(function () {
    var badge = $(this).find(".badge");
    var count = <?php echo $notification_count; ?>;

    if (count > 0) {
        badge.text(count);
    } else {
        badge.hide();
    }
});
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var url = "../inc/delete_msg.php?msg_id="+id;
        $(this).closest('.msg-content').next('hr').remove();
        $(this).closest('.msg-content').remove();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: success,
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed to Delete');
            }
        });
    });
function success() {
    $(".badge").text(<?php echo $notification_count - 1;?>);
    $('.modal-title').after(
        '<div class="alert alert-success delete-success-alert text-center" role="alert" id="delete_success_alert">' +
        'Message Deleted</div>');
    $('#delete_success_alert').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $('#delete_success_alert').slideUp(500);
    });
}
```

What can I do to fix this? The database updates both times, the div is removed both times. It's just this badge that I can't figure out.

Comment: where do you put the above javascript code ? in `<head>` or in a separate file ? if it's a separate file does it have .php extension ?

Comment: The message modal and above JS code is in my header.php file, which doesn't actually contain a head tag. It only contains the bootstrap navbar and the message modal. The head tag is on every page right underneath where I include('header.php');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple, looking at this line :

```
$(".badge").text(<?php echo $notification_count - 1;?>);
```

When will the php code execute ? you expect it to execute for every ajax request but you're wrong, it will only be executed on the server when the browser requests the file/page containing the javascript code you have and so your code will be equivalent to :

```
$(".badge").text(2); // 2 if we have 2 messages
```

So no matter how many ajax request you make and succeed you'll always put the badge text to 2 and only until page refersh the php code will be executed again.

Now to solve the problem first you have a `count` variable that captures the initial messages count from the server, I suggest using that variable like this :

```
count--;
$(".badge").text(count);
```

This code is javascript code and will be executed on ajax success and it's supposed to work.

From now on remember which code is executed when, php code is a server-side code, it's executed on the server , the browser won't get any php code , javascript code is client-side code, the browser will receive it and execute it, when you put php code inside javascript code it's like "hey browser execute this code" where "this code" is dynamic depending on the output of php code.

Comment: That helped! I created a count variable that was assignned to $('.badge').text() and placed it in the on('click') function. With every click I decremented the count variable, and if count == 0, then I did badge.hide(); Thanks for your help.